# Is el.onclick removed when removeChild(el) is called?

Tags: javascript

The following code creates and removes a button with an onclick listener.

Does the onclick listener persist after the element is removed from the DOM?

```js
let el = document.createElement('button')
el.innerHTML = "Test Button"
el.onclick = function(){
    alert('A Click Happened')
}

document.body.appendChild(el)
document.body.removeChild(el)
```

Bonus: Is the same true for `el.addEventListener('click',() => { alert('clicked') })`?

Comment: Logically: How can the listeners attached to the element persist after the element is destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not persist because you are removing the element with the `onClick()` attribute. The same is not true for `addEventListener()`.

I feel like I am answering a test question for you, but I hope it helps. **:)**

Comment: Whether handlers persist or not has nothing to do whether DOM elements are in DOM. It's about whether there is a reference to the element somewhere in code.

Comment: He is defining the function inside the element. Therefore removing the element removes the function. There is no reason for it to persist since it only targets the referencing element.

Comment: Removing an element is not the same as garbage collecting an element.